# Add to macro in a class file

Tags: macros, document-classes

I am trying to make a command much like \author works in the article class (I did not understand how this was implemented in article.cls). The function must take two arguments and expand the \container variable whenever the \addToContainer command is used. Here is my try:

```
\documentclass{test}

\addToContainer{First Arg 1}{First Arg 2}
\addToContainer{Second Arg 1}{Second Arg 2}
\title{Test article}

\begin{document}
The container contains the following: 

\printContainer
\end{document}
```

with the following class file

```
\ProvidesClass{test}

\LoadClass{article}

\let\containerSep\@empty%
\def\container{}%
\def\@addToContainer[#1]#2{\g@addto@macro\container{%
      \containerSep#1:~#2\def\containerSep{\unskip,\hspace{1em}}}}% 

\newcommand{\printContainer}{%
\container
}
```

The expected output should then be

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what the expected output should be? My impression is that your purpose does not really have to do with the way `\author` is implemented.

Comment: sure, I have updated the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the way `\author` is implemented. The expansion of `\maketitle` in your document uses the macro `\@author` which is predefined to give an error. When you write `\author{Name}` befome `\maketitle`, TeX expands this to `\def\@author{Name}`, and calling `\maketitle` issues no error but prints the author's name.

This being said, here is a possible implementation of what you want. I prefer using a token list in order to avoid expansion issues. Instead of first defining the separator to be empty and having `\addToContainer` redefine it, I let `\addToContainer` redefine itself at the first call.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newtoks\@container
\def\container{\the\@container}

\def\addToContainer#1#2{%
   \@bsphack
   \@container{\ignorespaces#1\unskip:~\ignorespaces#2\unskip}%
   \def\addToContainer##1##2{%
      \@bsphack
      \@container\expandafter{\the\@container,\hspace{1em}\ignorespaces##1\unskip:~\ignorespaces##2\unskip}%
      \@esphack
   }%
   \@esphack
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\parindent=0pt
\parskip=\bigskipamount

This should be empty: (\container)

\addToContainer{Call 1 Arg 1}{Call 1 Arg 2}
(\container)

% see that spaces are ignored
\addToContainer{ Call 2 Arg 1 }{ Call 2 Arg 2 }
(\container)

\addToContainer{Call 3 Arg 1}{Call 3 Arg 2}
(\container)

% the \@bsphack and \@esphack ensure that no space is introduced in the output
See \addToContainer{Foo}{Bar} this\\
(\container)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot

Comment: An additional question: How do you reset the \container variable, say, after each sectionheader? \titleformat{\section}{\bf}{}{0pt}{}[\def\rowContainer{}] in the class file doesn't do the trick

Comment: @user253249 You can define e.g. `\def\resetcontainer{\global\@container{}}`.